# Check if HTMLCollection contains element with empty value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hey I have a short question. I am learning JS (Vue.js) at the moment and now I have an example, where I have some inputs with the same class name.

```
<input class="checkInput" placeholder="firstname"/>
<input class="checkInput" placeholder="lastname"/>
<input class="checkInput" placeholder="age"/>
<button @click="saveData">Save</button>
```

Now when i click on the save button I trigger a method, which gives me an HTML Collection of all inputs with the `checkInput` class.

```
var val = document.getElementsByClassName("checkInput");
```

Now I want to iterate over this collection and check if one of the input values is empty.

```
 for (let item of val) {
   var y = item.value;
        
   if (y=="") {
     //Do save
   } else {
     //Empty Input Message to the user
   }
}
```

The problem is, that when for example the second input is empty and I click the save button, it executes the save method either because it checks every element step by step. How can I check the whole HTMLCollection at first and then execute the method? (And no I do not want to use a form)

Comment: Your class is `checkInput`, but you get elements by class name `inputCheck`.

Comment: Don't know about vue, but in bare DOM you could simply do `document.querySelectorAll(".checkInput:placeholder-shown")`.